# Shader Maker version 130 is not supported

Tags: glsl, macos

I am trying to compile a vertex shader with Shader Maker and if I try to use the version 130 it says:

> Compiling Vertex Shader
>   ERROR: 0:3: '' :  version '130' is not supported
>
> Compiling Fragment Shader

I need to use the version 130. Now I installed Shader Maker from it's site. I wonder if there is a way to use the version 130, what should I do?

Comment: Your system doesn't support GLSL 1.30 (OpenGL 3.0+), see if there's a software update to get you a newer version of OpenGL. From what I've noticed, Apple doesn't give OS X that great of OpenGL support though. The one programmer on our team with a Mac only has OpenGL 2.1, so our shaders target GLSL 120 while the rest of us have OpenGL 3.3+

Comment: It looks like OS X 10.7 (Lion) has OpenGL 3.2 support, see if you can update to that.

Comment: I have mountain lion.

Comment: Maybe Shader Maker is requesting a legacy profile instead of a core one. I don't have any experience with Shader Maker and I don't have access to a mac in the near future, so I can't really help you out more than that.

Comment: I feel like I want to use linux :)

Comment: I get the same error on linux :(

Comment: Try using the [Mesa 3D](http://www.mesa3d.org/) software renderer on Linux, it supports OpenGL 3.1/GLSL 1.40, but first make sure you've got the proper graphics card drivers installed. Perhaps the model of your Mac has a GPU that's a bit too old to support OpenGL 3.0...

Comment: Sorry but how do I see if I have a proper graphic card? I know the model (Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB), but how to see if it supports OpenGL 3.0?

Comment: Call `glGetString(GL_VERSION);` and output the result to the console. Alternatively, use Google to check it for your specific graphics card. From the looks of it, on OS X, only 2.1 is supported on the HD Graphics 3000. http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/device/Intel%20HD%20Graphics%203000

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about technical support for a specific tool.